# How to easily hide an echo after submit in a PHP form?

Tags: php, cookies

I'm working with cookies and I need to show a message saying that 'x' cookie is not set until I introduce a value in a form, then after I click submit I need to show a message saying that 'x' cookie is set, but I need to 'hide' the previous message.

```
<?php
$cookie_name = NULL;
$cookie_value = NULL;
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "Name Surname";

setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time()+86400 );

echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
  if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
     echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
     echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
     echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
 } 
}
?>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That are basics!

```php
$cookie_name = NULL;
$cookie_value = NULL;
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "Name Surname";

setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time()+86400 );

// Inital value of output
$output = "Cookie named {$cookie_name} is not set!";

// Check if method is POST and if cookie is set
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    // Overwrite output
    $output = "Cookie {$cookie_name} is set!<br>Value is: {$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]}";
}

// Show output
echo $ouput;
```

Comment: Nevermind I had the output inside the if, now its working fine. Thank you.